Tippy tooltip not working in server side datatable render function
I am creating an index on posts using Blade and I am having a problem in my code: tippy tooltip is not working on render function of datatable serve-side.
I am not getting any errors; every time I hover over the column where the tooltip is defined (description (body) column) I cannot see it.
Where am I going wrong?
FILE BLADE:


<x-layout>
    <h3>List posts</h3>
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>TITLE</th>
              <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
              <th>PUBLISH</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@6"></script>
    <script>
        new DataTable('#example', {
            ajax: "{{ route('retrieveposts') }}",
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            columns: [{
                    data: 'id',
                    name: 'id'
                },
                {
                    data: 'title',
                    name: 'title',
                    render: function(data, type, row) {
                        return `
                            <strong id="title_${row.id}" class="title"> ${data} </strong>                    
                        `;
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: 'body',
                    name: 'body',
                    render: function(data, type, row) {
                        return `
                        <div data-tippy-content="Tooltip">
                            <span id="value_description_${row.id}"> ${data}</span>
                         </div>
                         `;
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: 'is_publish',
                    name: 'is_publish',
                    render: function(data, type, row) {
                        return `
                        <span> ${data} </span>                         
                        `;
                    }
                },
            ]
        });
        
        tippy('[data-tippy-content]')

    </script>

</x-layout>




You are letting DataTable load the content via Ajax, so that is asynchronous. By the time tippy('[data-tippy-content]') executes, these elements won't even have been added to the DOM yet. And it doesn't look like this is "live", so you will need to initialize this after the events have rendered - the draw event seems like a suitable candidate to trigger that.

Can you tell me exactly what I should do?

Subscribe to the draw event, and initialize your tippy elements from within the callback function. https://datatables.net/manual/events#Listening-for-events

@C3roe Perfect, I tried this and it worked. Thank you very much
